# find all the radio button in a html and copy this button with whole attributes and values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a JS function that can search all "input[type]=radio" button and output them with all original attribute and value in a new div.

For example:

I want to select all the radio button part and output them in "div1"

```
<div id=main>
<input type="text" name="_nkw" id="_nkw" size="50" maxlength="300" value="" placeholder="Enter keywords or item number">
<select name="_in_kw" id="_in_kw" size="1">
<option value="1" selected="selected">All words, any order</option>
<option value="2">Any words, any order</option>
<option value="3">Exact words, exact order</option>
<option value="4">Exact words, any order</option>
</select>
<input type="radio" id="LH_PrefLocRadio" name="_fsradio2" value="&amp;LH_PrefLoc=1" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
...(there contain some other items)
<input type="radio" disabled="disabled" class="from_sellers_aspect_chbx" checked="checked" id="LH_SpecificSeller_id" name="_fsradio" value="&amp;LH_SpecificSeller=1">
</div>

<div id=div1>
<p id="output"></p>   
</div>
```

Then some output should appear in div1 section like:

```
<div id=div1>
<input type="radio" id="LH_PrefLocRadio" name="_fsradio2" value="&amp;LH_PrefLoc=1" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" disabled="disabled" class="from_sellers_aspect_chbx" checked="checked" id="LH_SpecificSeller_id" name="_fsradio" value="&amp;LH_SpecificSeller=1">
</div>
```

In the browser, it shows like there are some more radio buttons appear in the button of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone the elements and append them to output

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

```
jQuery('#main input[type=radio]').clone().appendTo('#output')
```

Comment: Thank you! your method works! However, what if I want to also add their "label for" attribute? I just realized I just ignore this label!

Comment: Asumming the radio and label are inside a parent span (for instance) you could use a selector for those labels and clone them.

Comment: But I cannot find a method if the codes are not in good format(ex. they are not inside one parent span)... It's frustrating.

Comment: You need to relate labels with their respective radios.